# Mimetype not known on KDE (open-xdg, kde-open)

Tags: linux, kde, xdg

## My system

Archlinux with KDE, all upgrades done. I have libreoffice installed.

## The problem

Every time I open a file from the terminal (for ex: `open-xdg mypdf.pdf`) I have a buch of warnings (see below). I know it's just warning, so it's not a real problem, but it annoying to have all this in your terminal every time...

**Do you have an idea of how to correct it ?** I'm not sure it's KDE-based, but who knows

## What I've tried so far

When I go in `/usr/share/mime/subclasses` and remove all the lines given below (by hand), it disappears...until the next upgrade.

### After reading answer

It still doesn't work. What i've did follows

```
$ xdg-mime default libreoffice-impress.desktop application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12
$ xdg-mime default libreoffice-impress.desktop application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12
```

and the `$ grep -i libre ~/.local/share/applications/*` gives:

```
/home/olivier/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
/home/olivier/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-impress.desktop
/home/olivier/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-impress.desktop
/home/olivier/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-impress.desktop
```

## The symptom

```
$ kde-open mypdf.pdf 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(6749) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12"
```

Thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in KDE: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343468 The comments there suggest to simply replace the faulty strings by hand until the bug is fixed upstream.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove these unknown lines from `/usr/share/mime/subclasses`

```
sudo cp /usr/share/mime/subclasses /usr/share/mime/subclasses.bak
sudo vim /usr/share/mime/subclasses
# remove all lines containing unknown mime types e.g. application/vnd.ms-excel
```

The result of diff

```
diff /usr/share/mime/subclasses.bak /usr/share/mime/subclasses
```

should be like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11907686/).

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to update the desktop database and mime database.
try the following commands in your terminal:

`$ update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
$ update-mime-database    ~/.local/share/mime`

for additional information see [this](http://blog.radevic.com/2012/02/how-to-set-default-apps-aka-how-to-use.html) link.

Comment: Just tried... Didn't work. I read your link

Comment: I don't know how to use your link: It don't speak about the mimetype things ? Thx for your proposition

Comment: I just updated the link on how on how to use xdg-mime.

Comment: `xdg-mime default libreoffice-impress.desktop application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12` should work then? Because it's not the case...

Comment: No other idea? I'm still with my pb...

Comment: See my edit to show what i've tried according to your answer

Comment: user2459714 Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

one has to manually fix the mime-types, which is the actual problem:

```
cp /usr/share/mime/subclasses /usr/share/mime/subclasses.bak
sed -i 's:macroEnabled:macroenabled:g' /usr/share/mime/subclasses
cat /usr/share/mime/subclasses
```

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278(office.12).aspx &
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt